# has_many through associations where and select results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

So I'm trying to filter results using WHERE condition but it's not working.

```
class Physician < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, through: :appointments
 end

class Appointment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
 end

class Patient < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, through: :appointments
end
```

and what I'm doing here is:

```
patients = Patient.joins(:physicians).includes(:physicians).where(:appointments => {:sick => true })
```

However, what I'm getting is the following:

```
"results": {
  "patient": {
    "id": 2,
    "patient_name": "Rob"
   },
   "physicians": [
    {
      "id": 4,
      "physicians_name":...
      "sick":false
    ... ,
    {
      "id": 7,
     "physicians_name":...
     "sick":true
     ... 
     ... ,
      {
      "id": 7,
      "physicians_name":...
      "sick":false
     ... 
     ]
    }
```

So as you noticed, I'm NOT getting only physicians with sick=true. any suggestions?

**Update**:
This is my serializer

```
class PatientSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :records

 def records
    { info: records_info }
 end

 def records_info
  object.appointments.map do |a|
  a.attributes.merge(a.physician.attributes)
 end
```

end
end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `sick` attribute is stored on the `appointment`, you should `joins(:appointments)`, instead of `joins(:physicians)`.

Given that, this should return the results that you're looking for:

```
patients = Patient.joins(:appointments).includes(:physicians).where(appointments: { sick: true })
```

The reason for this is that the conditions in the `where` clause need to reference the joined tables.  Since the `physicians` table isn't used in the `where` clause, it's not needed to be explicitly joined; however, the `appointments` table does need to be explicitly joined.

The `includes(:physicians)` allows "eager loading" of the `physicians` records, which prevents this from becoming an N+1 query when accessing each physician's data in the serializer.

Comment: thank you, Michael, "sick" is stored in the "appointments" table, not the physicians table. consider sick as metadata I want to store in the appointments table.

Comment: Ah, I see that the attributes are merged in the output; that wasn't clear.  You probably just need `joins(:appointments)` instead of `joins(:physicians)` in your original query.  You should leave the `includes(:physicians)` in order to avoid the N+1 query.

Comment: can you update your answer above so i can mark it as resolved ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe `includes(:physicians)` is causing an eager loading, which makes the where clause not work as expected. Can you take it out and see if it fixes it? you can stick it at the end and see if it helps too.

Comment: thank you, I did remove it, but did not have any effect. I also put it at the end and I got the same results. what is the issue here? please note that "sick" is stored in the  appointments table (which is the linking table).